# Convex Optimization - Minimizing the Frobenius Norm of a Matrix with Linear Inequality Constraint of its Vectorization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, least-squares

I have the following optimization problem:

Minimize $\|X\|_F$ subject to $Ax\le b$

Where $X$ is a matrix in $\mathbb{R}_{n\times n}$ of variables, $x$ is the $n^2$ vector of those variables and $A\in \mathbb{R}_{n^2\times n^2},b\in\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the **Frobenius norm** $\|X\|_F = \sqrt{\text{tr}(AA^T)}$.

If I understand correctly, this is a convex optimization problem and can be solved with convex optimization tools, but my search did not find an explicit treatment of the subject and I believe I'm missing obvious tricks.

What is the standard way of solving this problem using convex optimization? Are there any transformations which makes this, e.g. a semidefinite linear programming problem? A quadratic programming problem? etc.

Comment: There is no constraint that $X$ be positive semi definite, right?  The Frobenius norm of $X$ is simply the two norm of $x$.

Comment: How large is $n$? How much memory does $A$ take up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Minimizing $ {\left\| X \right\|}_{F} $ is equivalent of minimizing $ {\left\| X \right\|}_{F}^{2} $ which is equivalent of minimizing $ {\left\| x \right\|}_{2}^{2} $ where $ x = \operatorname{vec} \left( X \right) $, namely the [Vectorization Operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) applied on $ X $.

Now you can write your problem as:

$$\begin{align*}
\arg \min_{x} \quad & \frac{1}{2} {\left\| C x - d \right\|}_{2}^{2}  \\
\text{subject to} \quad & A x \leq b
\end{align*}$$

Where $ C = I $ and $ d = \boldsymbol{0} $.

Now all you need is to utilize [Linear Least Squares solver which supports Linear Inequality constraints](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2416843/33).

Comment: That's not L1 minimization, Alec.

Answer (score 2):

Since $\|X\|_F=\|x\|_2$, this is most naturally formulated as a second-order conic problem (SOCP).