# Why is this not a closed form solution to non-negative Least squares?

Tags: convex-optimization, closed-form, lagrange-multiplier, least-squares

According to [Solving Non Negative Constrained Least Squares by Analogy with Least Squares (MATLAB)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/561696/solving-non-negative-constrained-least-squares-by-analogy-with-least-squares-ma)
and all resources I have looked up regarding this topic, the non-negative least squares problem

$$
\min \frac 1 2 || \Phi w - y ||^2, \\ 
\text{s.t} \, w_i \ge 0 
$$
has no closed form solution. But what if we naively do Lagrangian constraint optimization?
The Lagrangian is given by
$$
L(w, \lambda) = \frac 1 2 (\Phi w - y)^T(\Phi w - y) - \lambda^T w
$$
Taking the derivative w.r.t $w$ and setting it to $0$, we get the optimal primal solution
$$
w^* = (\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} (\Phi^T y + \lambda).
$$
Looking at the dual function $g(\lambda) = L(w^*, \lambda)$, its derivative is given by
$$
\frac {\text{d}g}  {\text d \lambda} = - (\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} (\Phi^T y + \lambda).
$$
Setting it to zero yields
$$
\lambda = - \Phi^T y.
$$
However, we have the constraint that all multipliers need to be non-negative. This results in the dual solution
$$
\lambda^* = \max(- \Phi^T y, 0),
$$
where the $\max$ operator is defined per dimension. This results in the closed form solution

$$
w^* = (\Phi^T \Phi)^{-1} (\Phi^T y + \max(- \Phi^T y, 0)).
$$

Am I going wrong somewhere? If so, where?

Comment: Do you have a justification for the step "This results in the dual solution" ?

Comment: Ah I see the problem, I generalized from the one-dimensional convex problem that if the optimum is at a negative point, you can simply clamp it to zero. However, in multidimensional problems this might not be the correct solution.

Comment: Happy to help :-)

Comment: @G.Fougeron. Just out of curiosity : may I ask where you are located ? I am in Pau. Cheers :-)

Comment: I'm in the Paris area

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok thanks to G. Fougeron, I realized that the optimal lambda cannot be obtained by just taking a maximum per dimension with $0$. While this works for a one-dimensional objective, with a multi-dimensional objective this leads to a wrong solution.