# Least squares with matrix solution with constraints

Tags: matrix-equations, least-squares

I am trying to solve
$$A B = C$$
$B$ is a known $N\times M$ matrix, $C$ is a partially known $L\times M$ matrix, and $A$ is an unknown $L\times N$ matrix, with $L<N$. If $C$ were fully known, I could just use a least-squares solution, which can be calculated efficiently. Alas, of some entries of $C$ I know only that they are positive (in fact, all entries of $C$ are either known to be $0$, or known to be positive. We can scale the problem such that all positive entries of $C$ are, say, $>1$). I'm trying to solve for $A$ (up to a factor). Can $A$ be determined efficiently and if so, how?

A significant amount of literature exists on the subject of least squares solutions with inequality constraints (see e.g. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/69613/linear-least-squares-with-inequality-constraints)), but it is not clear to me if this problem can be reduced to the form typically found in the literature:
$$\text{min}\|A x-b\|\text{ s.t. }G x\geq h$$
In fact, I suspect that it cannot be reduced to that form.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?
\begin{equation}
\underset{{\underset{
\text{and }\left(AB\right)_{i,j}\geq 0
}{
A \text{ such that } \left(AB\right)_{\text{known}
}}=C_{\text{known}}}}{\min}\left\|AB-C\right\|_{\text{some suitable matrix norm, root of elementwise sum of squares for instance}}
\end{equation}
Here you would have a mixture of equality and inequality constraints.

Also, if you need inequality constraints *only*, but you have let's say $e\left(x\right)=0$, you can always realize these constraints as $e\left(x\right)\leq0$ and $-e\left(x\right)\leq0.$

remark: uniqueness does not nescessairily hold.

Comment: Alas, the system is over-determined, constructing a search space of exact solutions is not possible.

Comment: Not neccessairily. That depends on the rank of $B$ and on the known entries for $C$. (Take $B=0$ and $\text{known}=\emptyset$ for instance.)